# Why Java Beans are called "beans"?

Tags: java, javabeans

I am a Java developer and I am working with Beans everyday. I am curious about the history of the name "Bean". Does it just comes from coffe bean, or is there something else?

Comment: "Java coffee refers to coffee beans produced in the Indonesian island of Java." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_coffee) That also explains coffee mug.

Comment: You should also know that every .class file begins with the hexa string 0xCAFEBABE.

Comment: @ZenunKastrioti be careful. Java seems cute but it can tear you apart with timeouts and out of memory errors.

Comment: I don't know but I find it strangely satisfying to serialize a java bean into "myObject.bean".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, indeed. It refers just to coffee beans ([which can be stored in jar, by the way ...](http://cupacabana.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/bean-jar.png))

Comment: Hah very interesting, I get it now. The jar thing is amazing :) It all seems so funny now :D

Comment: http://houseofjava.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/bean-jar.png link is dead

Comment: @gtiwari333 : fixed

Answer (score 5):

Yes it stands for a coffee bean..

Some trivia: Java stands for the Java coffee consumed by the developers

Answer (score 4):

I think that it also comes from the idea of "self-contained" (object). If you look at the coffee beans, they are scattered, i.e. unrelated to each other. Once Sun wanted to come up with such objects, which you could single out from your system and passiviate on the disk or marshall to another node of distributed system, they needed a name for that category of objects and thus they looked around, discovered them on the Java island and coffee around. But I do not think that coffee is only important. Why do you think that the type of the object is less important for its name than the connotation of Java language with the island in the Pacific rim?

Answer (score 3):

actually when they were developing `java`, the developers consumed so much of coffee so they made it as their symbol.

and then so as the `beans` are small parts of the coding they named it as beans corresponding to small coffee beans.

and finally those small parts are compressed and saved as one in a `.jar` file.
so you can can say **beans are stored/placed in a jar**

Comment: Yes, that's right. But Java was not the first choice. It was initially called "Oak" (because James Gosling had a view from out of his window on an oak tree that stood outside the Sun offices building), but that name had to be changed because it was trademarked by some other company.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter ya thats true, but as the question was _why is it called beans_ so explained that much part only